# String matches regexp

Tags: java, regex

I used perl, unix and java regular expression lot of time, but I'm surprised in java about that:

```
    "help".matches("^h")
```

is false!!

From java documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

"true if, and only if, this string matches the given regular expression"

```
     "help".matches("^h.*")
```

or

```
     "help".matches("^h.*$")
```

return of course true.

It's surprising only me?

Comment: what is the question? are we surprised?

Comment: Because is seems that the expression is interpreted as `"^expression$"` adding a `$` at the end of it. I was also expecting a match with the first example.

Comment: Java regex is dumb. You are completely right. The method matches IS broken. Take a look here: http://mentaregex.soliveirajr.com

Answer (score 1):

`"help"` does not macth `"^h"`. Only the first letter in `help` matches `"^h"`

Comment: But in this case `^` becomes useless. The beginning of the regex is always a `^`: why have it in the specs then?

Comment: I'm not sure that a `^` is always the beginning of a regex. For example, the `el` part in `help` matches the `lp` expression

Comment: what do you mean by `el` matches the `lp` expression? I did a couple of tests and really seems that you have to match the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a bit more strict than say perl or ruby. It's trying to match the entire string and "help" has an extra elp at the end that /^h/ won't match on.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-):

> Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

Not a substring, the whole string.

Comment: But in this case why have `^` and `$` if they are implicit in any match?

Comment: multiline mode, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE is one situation.

Comment: I see, I just imagined it was behaving as perl but in fact no :-) In the documentation for `MULTILINE` we can read _By default these expressions only match at the beginning and the end of the entire input sequence._. The default case is mentioned but makes no sense...